# New Line '\n' is not working in Typescript with <br/> aslo?

Tags: html, typescript, bootstrap-4, newline

New Line '\n' '
' is not working in Typescript

my example typescript code is

```
 this.custPartyAddress =  estimation.partyName + ',' + '\n' +
 estimation.partyAddress + ',' + estimation.partyLandMark + ',' + estimation.partyCity + '\n' +
 estimation.stateName + ', Pin :' + estimation.partyPostalCode + ',' + '\n' + 'India.';
```

Showing out put is

```
Raju, Sr Nagar,Near Teample,HYDERABAD Andhra Pradesh, Pin :500032, India.
```

if above using 
 in place of 
 its showing like Bellow

```
 Raju<br/>, Sr Nagar<br/>,Near Teample<br/>,HYDERABAD Andhra Pradesh<br/>, Pin :500032, India.
```

html databinding

```
{{custPartyAddress}}
```

i tried many ways didt get solution could u please suggest me solution ...

Comment: Have you tried tweaking CSS. [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use innerHTML to be interpreted as code

```
<div [innerHTML]="custPartyAddress"></div>
```

edit: 
instead using {{custPartyAddress}} you can wrap in another div container using example from above (be carefoul, maybe will be necesarry to apply some styles for new container, example width: 100%)

Comment: didt understand allexys .. where to call that .. im using databinding in html  like     {{custPartyAddress}}... if call same abovve in place of     {{custPartyAddress}} ..showing same result above ...no change occured ..

Comment: updated answer. just replace your variable with a div container

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with breaks in your text.